# Extract a substring from a field PLSQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, substr

I just start with `PL/SQL` and I need to extract certain information from a field where I have stored all XML text with approximately 4,000 characters, if not more, consulting the respective documentation I see that for what I need you can use the function `SUBSTR` or the function I `REGEXP_SUBSTR` do not know which of the two can be used in my case.

From all the text that I have stored in the field I need to extract exactly one specific data, the following is only a part of the text that I have in the field.

```
fechaAutenticacion="2019-10-17T17:14:23"
```

From this part of the text I need to extract what it contains `fechaAutenticacion`, I mean this part `2019-10-17T17:14:23` without its quotes and then display it in a new column.

The following is the query to the table and the field where I have all the text with more than 4,000 characters.

```
SELECT SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR
        FROM SPRCMNT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that pattern `''fechaAutenticacion="<DATE>"'` consistently indicates the part that you want to trap, you can use `regexp_substr()` like so:

```
select regexp_substr(sprcmnt_text_nar, 'fechaAutenticacion="([^"]+)"', 1, 1, null, 1) authentication_date
from sprcmnt
```

The parentheses define a capturing group within the matching part of the string; then, the last argument tells Oracle to return the first (only) captured group rather than the all match.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(sprcmnt_text_nar, '^.*fechaAutenticacion="([^"])".*$', '\1')
```